# nodemailer error when using dynamic email recipient

Tags: node.js, express, email, next.js, nodemailer

I have a NextJS app, with an api endpoint, that receives dynamic recipients from the frontend. It correctly gets the email through req.body but nodemailer formats them weirdly in the Transporter.sendMail function provided by nodemailer.

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<ResponseProps>
) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return;
  }

  const {
    Recipient,
  } = await req.body;



  const Transporter = await nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "my-email-host.de",
    port: 25,
    secure: false,
    debug: true,
    logger: true,
    tls: {
      rejectUnAuthorized: false,
    },
    ignoreTLS: true,
  });

const Email = await Transporter.sendMail({
    from: "<IT-organization@example.de>",
    to: Recipient,
    subject: "Employment process",
    html:"Test Email"
  });
};
```

The Recipient when receiving from the frontend is:
TestUser@test.de but when passed to the nodemailer function it gets formatted like this: TestUser@xn--test-st6e.de

Here is the Error:

```
Error: 
code: 'EENVELOPE',
  response: '550 Recipient address rejected',
  responseCode: 550,
  command: 'RCPT TO',
  rejected: [ 'TestUser@xn--test-st6e.de' ],
```

Is there any way to resolve this formatting?

Comment: We can't see where it comes from, but that domain decodes to tes䗰t.de

Comment: Its coming from Bereichsleiter = req.body, which if you print it out, shows the exact email but nodemailer changes the email address in the SendEmail function

Comment: You shouldn't be awaiting the `req.body` destructuring, e.g. `const { Recipient } = req.body;`.